# How do I get a single level of object details from php?

Tags: php, class, object, stack-trace

When I retrieve a stacktrace in php using debug_backtrace, I can have it include the object it was called from. Being able to see both the public and private properties of the object is extremely useful to me, however the object is too big to be usable. Due to some of the variables in it containing other objects, simply printing it out is not feasible - I tried writing the output of debug_print_backtrace to a file, and it reached 23G before something broke and it stopped outputting.

What I really need, is to get this output to limit itself to going one level deep - that is, to output all the properties of the object, but if one of those is another object, instead of further listing out that one all I need is the class name for it.

I know I can use get_object_vars to get the public properties of the object, but how do I get the private ones? print_r, var_export, var_dump, etc. are all useless, because I can't stop them recursing.

Comment: Reflection may be useful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: Something like [this](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#78851)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast objects to arrays, then iterate over the array. Private and protected properties are available too, prefixed with the class name enclosed with null-bytes. You can test this behaviour like so:

**Test:**

```
class Test
{
    private $parent;
    public function __construct($parent) {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }
}

$test = new Test(new Test(new Test(null)));
var_dump((array)$test);
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  ["�Test�parent"]=>
  object(Test)#2 (1) {
    ["parent":"Test":private]=>
    object(Test)#3 (1) {
      ["parent":"Test":private]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

Now that you have an array you can do a simple `foreach`, stripping the prefixes and differentiating between objects and other variables:

```
foreach((array)$test as $name => $property) {
    if (ord($name[0]) === 0) {
        $name = substr($name, strrpos($name, "\x0")+1);
    }
    echo $name, ":";
    if (is_object($property)) {
        echo "(object)", get_class($property);
    } else {
        echo var_export($property, true);
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

I'll leave the pretty-printing up to you.

Comment: Eh, close enough. The solution I actually used seems to have been deleted, but you can see it here: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#78851

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through object simply with foreach loop, as:

```
foreach($object as $property => $value)
   if (is_object($value))
      echo(get_class($value)."<br/>");
   else
      echo($property." => ".$value."<br/>");
```

Bear in mind though, that this will not show private properties. 
A broader explanation on how you can got over that can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: The link also shows why this is not reliable. The object might be an iterator and do something completely different than yielding its properties if iterated.

Comment: That is indeed correct - it might also have a defined __toArray() method, which I think will cause `foreach` to result in different results than expected.

Comment: PHP does not have `__toArray()` (yet?), only `__toString()`.

Comment: Blargh... silly me for taking things for granted :D (cue me checking how the hell do I have __toArray in my code and why does it work) :D

Comment: There are frameworks that make use of toArray or __toArray if they exist, but a foreach won't care about that ;)

Comment: Yup, I actually coded in __toArray method and am calling it directly. Again, silly me :)